# Duplicate results Add-MailboxPermissions using CSV and Splat (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

After connecting to Exchange V3 EXO PowerShell successfully running a script that creates mailboxes from a CSV file, this works without issue, however after this section is complete,
run `Add-MailboxPermission` calling the same CSV since want to run all together not separate scripts.

Complete code except for connection to Exchange V3 EXPO (2019 with latest CU)  which is at top of script:

```
$DLs = Import-Csv -Path E:\Temp\SharedMailBoxs\MBSTemplate_Test_.csv
$DLS | % {
    $paramNewMailBox = @{
       DisplayName                      = $_.DisplayName
       Alias                            = $_.Alias  
       PrimarySmtpAddress               = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
       Name                             = $_.DisplayName
       #User                            = $_.User -split " "
       #Identity                        = $_.Identity
       ModeratedBy                      = $_.ModeratedBy -split " "
    }
   

    Write-Host $DLS
    #Write-Host "User Parameter" $DLS.User
    #Write-Host "Mailbox" $DLS.Identity
     
    New-Mailbox @paramNewMailbox -Shared:$true  
    }
    Write-Host "Starting Permissions process" 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
$DLs2 = Import-Csv -Path E:\Temp\SharedMailBoxs\MBSTemplate_Test_.csv
$DLS2 | % {


  #  Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
    $paramAddMailboxPermission = @{
     User                             = $_.User 
     Identity                         = $_.Identity
     
    
     }
    #Write-Host $DLS2.DisplayName
    Write-Host $DLS2.User
    Write-Host $DLS2.Identity
    Add-MailboxPermission  $paramAddMailboxPermission -AccessRights:FullAccess -InheritanceType:All -AutoMapping:$false 
    #Write-Output "#Add-MailboxPermission -Identity = $_.DisplayName -User $_.User -AccessRights:FullAccess -InheritanceType:All -AutoMapping:$false"

 }
```

All column header in the CSV are correct and match the script, Mailbox creation works as expected.
When `Add-MailboxPermission` section is run it asks for parameter values for User (which it should get from parameter, `Write-Host`s for User and Identity report correctly), Identity fails with

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'.
Cannot convert value "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]" to type 
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter".
Error: "Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' cannot be converted to type
```

Ran `Write-Output` to see the results and the results are duplicated, so not sure if that is why the `Add-MailboxPermission` is failing as it can't read the output correctly from the splat parameters.
[image]

Anyone else have this issue ? If so, how was it resolved? Thank you

Comment: You forgot to splat `$paramAddMailboxPermission`: `Add-MailboxPermission @paramAddMailboxPermission` <-- `@` instead of `$`